# How can I generate a file with today's date in its name?

Tags: python, file, date

I have seen several post like this but nobody actually answer the question straight to the point.

I'm creating a file in Python like this:

```
f = open('myfile.extension','w')
```

What should I add to this line to add the date in the filename?

I'm using `import time` and I can get any current date in any other part of my script, but I don't know how to add the date...

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are trying to add the date to the filename

```
 from datetime import datetime

 datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S')
 f = open('myfile_'+datestring+'.extension', 'w')
```

You can change the format however you like. The above will print out `datestring` like so:

```
datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S')
'2015/08/07_16:07:37'
```

Of course since this is a filename you may not want to have the `/`, so I would recommend a format like the following:

```
datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
'2015-08-07-16-07-37'
```

Here's a full run of all of the above:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
>>> f = open('myfile_' + datestring + '.ext', 'w')
>>> f.name

'myfile_2015-08-07-16-24-23.ext'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want it in the filename:

```
from datetime import date

filename = 'myfile_{}.extension'.format(date.today())

f = open(filename, 'w')

print f.name  # 'myfile_2015-08-07.extension'
```